# why deployed wars using tomcat manager not showing in Tomcat_home/webapps folder?

Tags: java, tomcat6

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

I deployed wars using tomcat manger. i am able to access all the deployed apps also..but my question is why i am not able to see the deployed wars in web apps folder.

Comment: Do you need to see the deployed wars? Why does it matter?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Steve C.    I have some htm and jsp files as part war...i dont want to redeploy every time..directly i want to modify those files in the webapps folder itself

Comment: The deployment tools in your IDE will normally manage this for you.